# Visual Studio 2013 SSRSS - Column Grouping showing Nothing

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

In my ssrs report, I have an 'All' parameter which will show all of the offices associated with a division.  SSRS is showing blanks for 2 months, but not the rest of the months.  I am unable to have the groups not show the missing months or am I unable to show zero's in the data.  Please Help.

Using VS 2013, SSRS

Comment: I don't get what you're saying - can you take a screenshot of the rendered report and upload to IMGUR.com and add the link to your question? Is the data in your query? Are you sure your parameter is working?

Comment: look into `isnothing()` in ssrs. and also post what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach your query here? I think you can control this issue through your sql query by using left join to a table containing all of months (maybe a temp table).